# How can I find all the lakes in a region (bounded by polgon) in earth engine?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-engine

The problem statement is that a region of interest is given.

I need to find all the lakes in a polygon bounded region using the NDWI index for water bodies, which are at a height of more than 1500m. Then display the changes in the area of lake's surface water starting from the year 1984 till 2018 on a 2-year interval in a table like structure in Google Earth Engine. I have used Landsat 5 and 7 data.

I have created the following code: 
[Earth Engine Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5336b4b14a8e86cb9c10addcb78d052b)

Now I need to display the results in the polygon marked region in a table sort of structure in the following format:-
Rows - (Lake 1, Lake 2, Lake 3... Lake n) 
Columns - (Surface Area in 1984, Surface Area in 1986, ....2018)

How should I go about doing it?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Load an elevation layer and use .where and .gt.

Comment: Please check this code and provide some suggestions :- https://code.earthengine.google.com/bbbeee9dbb7b09b83c3cb155d24c1648

Comment: @RudradeepDeb you should update the question with the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question in regard of the code posted in the comments, hopefully the question is updated with the code posted in the comments.

**Filtering:** ok.

Just a comment, I wouldn't name an image collection variable with name `img`, it's just confusing to me, but variables names are up to you.

```js
var mf = ee.Filter.calendarRange(10, 12, 'month');

var img1 = ee.ImageCollection(l5
            .filterDate('1984-01-01','1999-12-31')
            .filterBounds(roi)
            .filter(mf));

var img2 = ee.ImageCollection(l7
            .filterDate('2000-01-01','2018-12-31')
            .filterBounds(roi)
            .filter(mf));
```

**add NDWI**: This is your code:

```js
var addNDWI = function(image){
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B4']).rename('NDWI');
  var ndwiMask = ndwi.gte(0.3);
  return image.addBands(ndwi);
};
var image1 = img1.map(addNDWI);
var image2 = img2.map(addNDWI);
```

you are not saving `ndwiMask`, so you won't be able to use it outside of this function. Again, I wouldn't name them `image` as they are not images but image collections.

**elevation mask**: you have to select the `elevation` band:

```js
var elevMask = elevation.select('elevation').gt(1500)
```

This mask image will have ones where elevation is greater than 1500 and zeros where not.

**applying masks**: in this part you have to remember that Earth Engine uses functional programming, so objects are not mutable, this means that you cannot update the state of an object using a method, you have to catch the output of the method you are calling. Here you need ndwi mask, so you have to compute it with NDWI band.

```js
var mask = function(image){
  var ndwiMask = image.select('NDWI').gt(0.3)
  var ndwi_masked = image.updateMask(ndwiMask);
  return ndwi_masked.updateMask(elevMask);
};

var maskedImg = image1.map(mask);  // ImageCollection!
var maskedImg2 = image2.map(mask);  // ImageCollection!
```

**Visualizing**: As the results are `ImageCollection`, when you add it to the map EE makes a mosaic and that is what you would see. Keep that in mind for further processing.

```js
var ndwiViz = {bands: ['NDWI'], min: 0.5, max: 1, palette: ['00FFFF', '0000FF']};
Map.addLayer(maskedImg, ndwiViz, 'Landsat 5 masked collection');
```

Comment: Updated the code a bit. Also added the updated link to the code in the question. Now I need to display the changes in the area of lake's surface water starting from the year 1984 till 2018 on a 2-year interval in a table like structure in Earth Engine. Also could you please check the display on the map?

Comment: but this this answer the original question?? you should not update the question making a new question. Keep the original question here and make another post if required

Comment: Here is the new question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56862920/9937666 . Please check it out.